# C#- Selenium with Chrome testing: Element is not clickable at point Other element would receive the click

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, coded-ui-tests, selenium-chromedriver

Here are the details of my Development Environment:

Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Update 4
Google Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m
Windows 7 Professional with 32-bit Operating System
Coded UITest Builder 11.0.60315.1

Our software team is creating an ASP.NET web application, and the customer has requested that we use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 with Microsoft CodedUI to run automated tests.

I ran our ASP.NET application in Google Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m

I downloaded and installed the "Selenium components for Coded UI Cross Browser Testing"

Also, I've added the Selenium DLLs to my Microsoft Visual Studio  2012 CodedUI project.

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\blabblahblah\SeleniumConfigFiles\");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:2816/");
IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.00));
wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return       document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.LinkText("System")));
var btn = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("System"));
btn.Click();
```

Unfortunately, the last line of code always yields the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
   HResult=-2146233079
   Message=unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (163, 36). Other element would      receive the click: <div class="loading-screen">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=38.0.2125.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241075,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86)
   Source=WebDriver
   StackTrace:
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)      in     c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 1012
         at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute,     Dictionary`2 parameters) in         c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 846
         at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.InternalExecute(String    driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in     c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 729
         at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute,      Dictionary`2 parameters) in    c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement.cs:line 810
          at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click() in       c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement.cs:line 336
           at JigsawCUITChrome.UIMap.RecordedMethod1() in      d:\blahblahUIMap.Designer.cs:line 55
   at JigsawCUITChrome.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1() in d:\blahblah\CodedUITest1.cs:line 31
```

InnerException:

Could you please tell me how I can resolve the error above?

Comment: It's a very Inefficient solution, but just after navigating to the webpage driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:2816/"); I added a  Thread.Sleep(90000);  It still takes too Long.  Does anyway have a more efficient solution?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It says there's another control blocking the `btn`, namely the div "Loading Screen".  Check for modals or other controls, and when possible, use an ID or ClassName property to search by, as it's a bit quicker.

Comment: This question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094589/can-selenium-detect-whether-clickable-elements-are-being-covered-up-by-other-ele/ wants to throw this exception that you're running into. Do you know if the exception is coming from CodedUI, Selenium, or is your own customisation?

Comment: @david Exception was thrown because our website UI developers are using a UI interface w/ lot of UI elements.When all UI elements are loaded on to the browser, our UI developers use a div placeholder with a class value called loading-screen.The said loading-screen div element will stay in place until all the UI elements are loaded and in their proper places within the browser.Finally, the loading-screen div element will disappear.I modified UI test code so that it waited until  loading-screen div element disappears before it continues on to interacting with the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a blind wait, you can wait for the blocking element to go away

Selenium has no built in exists property or method, but you can easily make one.

```
public static bool Exists(IWebDriver driver, By locator)
{
    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(locator);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException) { return false; }
}

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\blabblahblah\SeleniumConfigFiles\");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:2816/");
IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.00));
wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return       document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.LinkText("System")));
wait.Until(drv => ! Exists(drv, By.CssSelector("div.loading-screen"); // Added wait here for the loading element to go away
var btn = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("System"));
btn.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also the same issue while working with chrome driver I have tried couple of scenario which worked for me.

Below are the solution that I tried

It mostly happens in Chrome so if you are mostly working with Firefox or IE then you will not be getting this exception.
Chrome does not calculate the exact location of element
Chrome always click in the middle of Element.
Some time you will get this exception due to Sync issue also.

http://learn-automation.com/how-to-solve-element-is-not-clickable-at-pointxy-in-selenium/

Comment: Please refrain from posting links, rather quote the relevant info from the page - in a year from now that link might no longer work.